# Proper way to define a .value with TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have used the format below to define a value using TypeScript, but I'm not sure if it's the "proper" way to do so.

```
module app.global {
    "use strict";
    export class GlobalInfo {
        userId: string;
        environment: string;
    }
    angular.module("bulkAddMemos")
        .value("GlobalInfo", GlobalInfo);
}
```

This works fine - I can inject it in my controllers and services and use it as shared storage for these values. Without TypeScript if I wanted to declare a default value for one of these object properties I could do this:

```
angular.module("bulkAddMemos")
    .value("GlobalInfo", { userId: "", environment: "TEST" });
```

I tried to do the same with TypeScript but neither of the approaches below worked. Any time I try to access the `environment` property it is `undefined`.

**Attempt 1**

```
module app.global {
    "use strict";
    export class GlobalInfo {
        userId: string;
        environment: "TEST";
    }
    angular.module("bulkAddMemos")
        .value("GlobalInfo", GlobalInfo);
}
```

**Attempt 2**

```
module app.global {
    "use strict";
    export class GlobalInfo {
        userId: string;
        environment: string;
        constructor(){
            this.environment = "TEST";
        }
    }
    angular.module("bulkAddMemos")
        .value("GlobalInfo", GlobalInfo);
}
```

Does anyone know how to define a `.value` using TypeScript in a manner that allows you to set default values for the properties? I know that I could bootstrap this and set a default value when the app starts up, but I'd really like to figure out how to do this without resorting to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
module app.global {
    "use strict";
    export class GlobalInfo {
        userId: string;
        environment: "TEST";
    }
    angular.module("bulkAddMemos")
        .value("GlobalInfo", new GlobalInfo);
}
```

`GlobalInfo` is class (i.e. `typeof GlobalInfo === 'function'`), so it should be instantiated in order for the value to be an object.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was missing some little detail, but try a Google search for "angular typescript value". :)